# Measure Thread idle time, blocking, etc

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

We are trying to fine tune our application for production. Under a single login everything is nice and quick. Under load of 250 to 750 simultaneous hits though things slow down considerably. I put stopwatch timers on suspected calls but they are executing very fast. So then I began to wonder if we had threading, backlog, etc. type delays. So I added a time in and time out metric. As you'll see below of the 11 seconds and 9000 milliseconds 11 seconds are spent on the wire waiting to get to the async method. So I was looking for help / information on how to log network hops and or thread pool wait times etc....or anything else you see may be worth investigating.

Snip from the originating method:

```
Debug.WriteLine("REPOBASE_Enter HttpAsync:::Endpoint Base is: {0} and uri is: {1}", baseAddress.AbsoluteUri, uri);
Stopwatch httpAsync = new Stopwatch();
httpAsync.Start();
Debug.WriteLine("REPOBASE_Enter HttpAsync Timeout: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(uri);

httpAsync.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine("REPOBASE_Exit HttpAsync elapsed:{0}", httpAsync.Elapsed);
```

The above snip will produce this in the output:

> Line 345: REPOBASE_Enter HttpAsync:::Endpoint Base is: http://localhost:57874/ and uri is: api/accounts/10553697
>
> Line 346: REPOBASE_Enter HttpAsync Timeout: 9:18:35 AM
>
> Line 350: REPOBASE_Exit HttpAsync elapsed:00:00:11.9159835

Over in the base service that the HttpClient is calling:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetById(long id)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("REPOBASE_Enter HttpAsync Timein: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    Debug.WriteLine("BASE_Enter GetById");
    Stopwatch baseGetById = new Stopwatch();
    baseGetById.Start();
     .....
```

And the base service produces this for output:

> Line 110: REPOBASE_Enter HttpAsync Timein: 9:18:46 AM:
>
> Line 111: BASE_ Enter GetById
>
> Line 112: BASE_ Exit default GetById Elapsed: 00:00:00.0015406

Comment: Did you try the concurrency analyser of visual studio?

Comment: You should use fiddler to record latency times. You can use [this plugin](http://www.logic-worx.com/index.php/tools-and-apps/fiddler-connection-simulator/) to simulate network latency issues and see how your web services holds up.

Comment: Slowing down under load is more likely to be related to thread context switching and GC overhead. There are profiling tools that can help you understand these impacts better. Without [a good code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), any specific suggestion provided here is pure speculation.

Comment: I don't see 11 seconds to get to the async method. I see an HTTP GET that takes 11 seconds to return. That may easily be because only 2 concurrent HTTP connections are allowed per domain, so the other 248 requests simply wait for their turn. To increase them set `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to the value you desire

Comment: BTW you can see this very easily if you use Visual Studio's [Concurrency Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537632(v=vs.120).aspx)